# How to configure the limit of concurrent requests to a remoting server with TcpChannel

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have a standard Remoting server with an underlying TcpChannel:

```
    IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
    props["port"] = portnumber;
    TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(props, null, provider);

    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
    string url = string.Format("AgentHost", portnumber);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
        typeof(RemotingAgentHostEndPoint),
        url,
        WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
```

It works fine but when at 200 parallel calls the clients receive a 
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:33333" exception.

I cannot find anywhere to override this limit - do any of you have a clue ?

Kind regards
Carsten Hess

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a limit for maximum number of concurrent half-opened tcp connections. This limit vary in different versions and configurations, but it is here. Google for tcpip.sys troubles for example - you will find various configuration options to override this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only for outgoing half-opened connections. My problem is to have more than 200 established connections with the server.

Comment: This limit is for TCP inbound connections. For sure. Look at something like http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html . Anyway .NET Remoting has nothing to do with connection limits serverside!